# Moving a Group of SVG Elements on Mouse Click

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events

I'm trying to move a group of circles when a user clicks one of them. The group only moves once on the first click, but not afterwards. Here's the sample code I'm using:

```
function move_circle(e)     
{
var grp = e.target.parentNode;
grp.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + 50 + ", " + 50 + ")");
}

<g onclick="move_circle(evt)">
  <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="25" fill="red"  />
  <circle cx="170" cy="120" r="5" fill="red"  />
</g>
```

Answer (score 7):

Every time that you click a circle, the event handler is setting the `transform` attribute of the `g` element to `"translate(50, 50)"`. I believe what you intended to do is to repeat the translation every time a circle was clicked. In other words, you want to compose the translation with the one that is already applied to the element. Like so:

```
function move_circle(e) {
  var g = e.target.parentNode,
      t;

  if (g.transform.baseVal.numberOfItems == 0) {
    g.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + 50 + ", " + 50 + ")");
  } else {
    t  = g.transform.baseVal.getItem(0),
    t.setMatrix(t.matrix.translate(50, 50));
  }
}
```

If no transformation has been applied, it will apply the translation as you were previously doing. If a transformation's already being applied to the element, then you use the existing transformation matrix, apply *another* translation to it, and then set the result of that to the transformation matrix of the element. (The `translate()` operation does not mutate the matrix. It returns a copy of the matrix with the operation applied to it. Thus, you have to update the transformation with that new matrix.)