# Best way to move a group of SVG elements

Tags: svg

I'm looking for the best way (the faster, the cleaner...) to move a group of SVG elements. I have three ways in mind :

- do a loop on all elements and, for each of us, change the x and y attributes
- group all elements in a svg element and change its x and y attributes
- group all elemnts in a g element and apply the method described here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14036803/2019761

Do you have an idea please ?

Comment: I'd chose the last option, wrap it around <g> element and move the entirety with `transform`, Avoid too many <svg> as it can get rather complex with similar <style> or <defs> within each <svg> (ie: too easy to mix 'em up)

Comment: I've recently been dealing with d3.js and I also before that adding the elements to a group and transforming the group is the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can move svg groups or elements with javascript

```
// translate svg element
function translate( _element , _x , _y )
{
  var transform = _element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0);   
  var mat = transform.matrix;   

  mat = mat.translate( _x, _y );  
  transform.setMatrix( mat );

}
```

see it in action:

http://www.janvas.com/illustrators_designers_developers/projects/janvas2D_web/examples_EN.php?exampleName=ufo_animation_EN

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking what is the best method between the three I've listed.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the better way is to move a group of elements.

If you look the example you can see that the ufo are translated
and the inner motor rotate inside of it.
(all moved elements are groups)

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -12.5067 69.4101)" id="ufo">
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 -2.842170943040401e-14)">
        <path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 21.6 2.8)" width="92.34371368613222" height="91.4899957511011" stroke-width="0.83" stroke-miterlimit="3" stroke="none" fill="url(#_1_)" d="M46.1,0 C71.67,0 92… "/>     
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(0.5 0.86 -0.86 0.5 74.6 24.1)" id="motor">
        <path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 9.7 -2.2)" width="13.11" height="13.5849" stroke-width="0.88" stroke-miterlimit="3" stroke="none" fill="url(#_4_)" d="M6.55,2.8… "/>        
    </g>
</g>
```

Answer (score 4):

Interacting with DOM methods involves JS <-> native code overhead. Browser implementers have been working hard to reduce this overhead, but it's never going to be free. If you're doing a lot of it, such as setting x and y on a lot of elements, you may start to see a significant performance impact. In this case setting positional properties just once on an `<svg>` or `<g>` container will likely help.

A more significant source of overhead is likely to be the work to repaint for the changes you make. If these changes are for a transform change, and if the transform's value changes multiple times in a short space of time, then most implementations will paint the content of the transformed SVG element into a cached offscreen surface and composite that surface instead of repainting each time. Recompositing can be a lot faster than repainting if the contents of the element are expensive to paint (say it contains a lot of children, or expensive filter effects), so if you're animating the transform of a `<g>` then you could well see much better performance.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I don't understand English very well, but the conclusion is that `<g>` is better than `<svg>` or both are equal ?